# how to manage this footnotes in table environment

Tags: tables, urls

I am trying to add a link inside the table to an url direction. I am not sure about how to do it. This is what I have but it doesn't work. Could you help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
%,draft
]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"
\emergencystretch=2em
\decimalpoint

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\captionof{table}{name}
\begin{tabular}{@{}clcc@{}}
\toprule
nº C & \textbf{j} & k &k \\ \midrule

 & 2-chlorobutyric\footnotemark{c} & 2.86 & 25 \\
 & 3-chlorobutyric\footnotemark{d} & 4.05 & 25 \\
 & guanidine & 13.6 & 25 \\
 & imidazole\cite{storey1964pka} & 6.99 & 25 \\
 & 2-aminoimidazole & 8.46* & 25\cite{storey1964pka}\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
Here I have some notes.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\footnotetext[c]{\url{https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Elisabeth_Bosch/publication/222627494_Dissociation_constants_of_neutral_and_charged_acids_in_methyl_alcohol_The_acid_strength_resolution/links/00463533c08df1ae05000000/Dissociation-constants-of-neutral-and-charged-acids-in-methyl-alcohol-The-acid-strength-resolution.pdf}
\footnotetext[d]{\url{https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Elisabeth_Bosch/publication/222627494_Dissociation_constants_of_neutral_and_charged_acids_in_methyl_alcohol_The_acid_strength_resolution/links/00463533c08df1ae05000000/Dissociation-constants-of-neutral-and-charged-acids-in-methyl-alcohol-The-acid-strength-resolution.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you use a `\item` command within `\tablenotes` and use `\tnote{}` as the docs suggest? What's wrong with the documented way?

Comment: No because the url is to big @TeXnician

Comment: I think you're committing a major mistake by providing great long URL strings when much shorter ones will do just fine. E.g., instead of the first long URL string, it suffices to state `\url{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222627494_Dissociation_constants_of_neutral_and_charged_acids_in_methyl_alcohol_The_acid_strength_resolution}`. Better yet, load the `hyperref` package and write `\href{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222627494_Dissociation_constants_of_neutral_and_charged_acids_in_methyl_alcohol_The_acid_strength_resolution}{Rived et al}`.

Comment: Incidentally, is there a reason for showing the same URL string twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any readers *ever* want to be shown, let alone want to look at for any length, a long URL string. (Do *you* look at long URLs for more than a fraction of a second?!) The shorter, the better.

Better still, don't show any URL strings at all -- not even in footnotes. Instead, load the `hyperref` package and use `\href{...}{...}` directives. Your readers will really appreciate it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, 
   top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, 
   headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=false,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,
   tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,
   factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\emergencystretch=2em
\decimalpoint

\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\caption{name}
\begin{tabular}{@{} clcc @{}}
\toprule
No.\ C & \textbf{j} & k &k \\ 
\midrule
 & 2-chlorobutyric\tnote{c} & 2.86 & 25 \\
 & 3-chlorobutyric\tnote{c} & 4.05 & 25 \\
 & guanidine & 13.6 & 25 \\
 & imidazole\cite{storey1964pka} & 6.99 & 25 \\
 & 2-aminoimidazole & 8.46* & 25\cite{storey1964pka}\\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[c] \href{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222627494_Dissociation_constants_of_neutral_and_charged_acids_in_methyl_alcohol_The_acid_strength_resolution}{Rived et al (1998)}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is good. But I am doing my thesis, the people who correct needs to have the links (not always but in this case it will be good).

Comment: @HernanMiraola - The only meaningful test of the correctness of a URL string is whether or not it lets readers navigate to where the author (i.e., you) wants them to go to. If an author provides a URL string but nothing else, i.e., not even a hyperlink to the site in question, it's exceedingly unlikely that any reader will make use of the information contained in the URL string. This actually raises a much bigger issue: Why are you providing URL strings to begin with? Why not directly provide citation call-outs (via `\cite`) to the publications in question?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But an hyperlink when someone reads my thesis on paper, doesn't helps..that's why I suppose adding the url..

Comment: @HernanMiraola - If somebody is reading your paper in paper (hardcopy) format, I'd say that showing that reader the full URL string pretty much guarantees that no useful purpose whatsoever is being served. Nobody expects this intrepid reader to sit down in front of a computer, open a browser window, and painstakingly type in, by hand, the multi-line URL string -- naturally, without typos -- just to verify that the URL string is actually correct and valid? For such a reader, providing correct and informative citation call-outs to the publications in question should be the only right way to go.